# Ruby - Delete from array of arrays based from Parameter

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm trying to write a function that will remove an array from a 3d array where an array has a matching String name.

```
before(:each) do
  @topic1 = Topic.new 4,'topic 1'
  @topic2 = Topic.new 7,'topic 2'
  @topic3 = Topic.new 5,'topic 3'
  @subject = Subject.new 'Module 1',2,5
end
```

parameters are No_of_Lectures and Name

```
@topics = [5,'Topic1'], [3,'Topic2'], [5,'Topic3']
```

Basically I'd like to remove the array where Name = 'Topic1' or return null if it's not in the list.

What I have so far is

```
def findTopic name
  @topics.find {|topic| topic.name == name }
end


def removeTopic name_in
  if @topics.findTopic(name)
    @topics.delete_if {|key, name| name == name_in } 
    topic
  else
    null
  end
end
```

Comment: What's the specific issue? That's how you delete an item from an array.

Comment: What about everything else? Would this function return the topic removed if it is removed and return null if its not in the list?

Comment: `topic` isn't defined in the method, so it wouldn't even run (unless it's a method as well).

Comment: Sorry didnt include that part. So are we good to go with rspec testing now? The function seems like its ok?

Comment: Probably should have been worrying the test first. But sure-if you're testing correctly you'll know if it's OK-that's kind of the point.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question needs some work. Please take the time to use correct grammar and punctuation, and indent your code correctly. The time you spend asking your question and making it format correctly will pay off in the answers you get; Not spending the time reduces the effort others will pay your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> a 3d array

Your arrays are two dimensional.

> return null if its not in the list.

`null` doesn't exist in ruby--there is `nil`, though.

```
def remove(target, array2D)

  results = array2D.reject do |arr|
    arr.last == target
  end

  results.size == array2D.size ? nil : results
end

test_arrays = [
  [[5,'Topic1'], [3,'Topic2'], [5,'Topic3']],
  [[5,'Topic4'], [3,'Topic5'], [5,'Topic6']]
]

test_arrays.each do |array2D|
  p remove('Topic2', array2D)
end

--output:--
[[5, "Topic1"], [5, "Topic3"]]
nil
```

On the other hand, a solution for this question:

> remove a topic from the list. Returns the topic removed; otherwise,
>   return null when topic is not currently in the list.

is:

```
def remove(target, array2D)

  array2D.each_with_index do |arr, index|
    if arr.last == target
      array2D.delete_at(index)
      return arr
    end
  end

  return nil

end

test_arrays = [
  [[5,'Topic1'], [3,'Topic2'], [5,'Topic3']],
  [[5,'Topic4'], [3,'Topic5'], [5,'Topic6']]
]

test_arrays.each do |array2D|
  p remove('Topic2', array2D)
end

--output:--
[3, "Topic2"]
nil
```

Comment: Thanks can you explain what the results = line does?

Comment: While true, this doesn't really address the original issue; using `delete` should work properly all other things being equal. Whether or not it's a good idea is a separate discussion!

Comment: @ChrisMaher, That assigns the return value of the method to the variable results.

Comment: @Dave. Thanks @ 7Stud Strange hearing null doesnt exist. Im following a tutorial and this is the exercise at the end. Heres the instructions. http://pastebin.com/g49YWGnL

Comment: @ChrisMaher It's sort of the same thing; Ruby's equivalent. One difference is that `nil` is a class in Ruby, `NilClass`, which is useful. Is this really a Ruby exercise? If so, it's too bad they didn't follow Ruby naming conventions (snake_case, not camelCase). I'd recommend changing the names to more Ruby-like ones.

Comment: Exercise was to write it in Java first and Junit test it. Then write in Ruby and Rspec test it. hence the naming problems. I want to be 100% certain im testing the right thing or im wrong before starting. So could i move to the testing now do you think?

Comment: @ChrisMaher, What you stated in your question is not what was asked for at that link.  See bottom of my answer for another solution.